# Unable to chat in stackoverflow

Tags: bug, chat

Yesterday I got some reputation but still not able to enter any room and chat.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to log in into the chat? What you posted so far got nothing to do with reputation, you are simply not logged in.

Comment: redirects on the same page :-( here is the [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.stackoverflow.com%2frooms%2f59481%2ftech-gossips)

Comment: This got nothing to do with reputation then. Same would happen even to Jon Skeet, if he will install HTTPS Everywhere.

Comment: Did you click the login link on the right top bar? Can you clear all cookies for chat.stackoverflow.com? Are you using an SE account or Google?

Comment: SE account and already tried on another browser

Comment: If I click on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ it redirects to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/